# Standalone Android CMake for externalNativeBuild

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, native

I've setup externalNativeBuild in my project with Android Studio 2.2.2 and it works good. Now I'm looking for CMake that it uses, but I can't find one. I know that there is one in "android-sdk-linux/cmake" and I could copy it, but I'd like to provide other developers from my team with straight download link. Also other developers don't really need to have Android Studio.

Using official CMake doesn't help because it doesn't have "Android Gradle" generators.

And it seems that there is no way to download it using Android SDK manager as well.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: seems too late, but just to converge it to [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704920/target-native-lib-is-not-a-directory/54932923#54932923)