# Why Android Studio 3 use cmake 3.6.0 as default?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

My Android studio is version 3.3.2 and i trying to link gradle to my native library, my module's build.gradle is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "MyModule"
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.10.2"  // The key line
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

If i don't specify the cmake version to '3.10.2', I am getting the following error:

> CMake '3.6.0' was not found in PATH or by cmake.dir property.
>       - CMake '3.10.2' found in SDK did not match requested version '3.6.0'.
>       - CMake '3.12.1' found in PATH did not match requested version '3.6.0'.
>       Install CMake 3.6.0

So I'am confused why is so! Why does it ask for the version of cmake itself to be 3.6.0.

Kindly review and give feedback.

Comment: you may refer to the answer for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704920/target-native-lib-is-not-a-directory)

Answer (score 15):

Try to add the configuration below to your gradle:

```
   externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.10.2" // here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also had to add this to local.properties: `cmake.dir=<path to...>/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404`

Comment: how to you set the local properties .In which file? tesch1

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J Set the line `cmake.dir=<path to...>/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404` in the file named `local.properties`

Comment: properties.setProperty("cmake.dir", yourpath) in your build.gradle if you are working on a remote system

Comment: Deserves more upvotes. This is easier than installing a different version on Ubuntu. When installing via apt you don't get to choose the version but you can change this to match what ubuntu gives you (which is the latest usually). Thanks!